# RedisStore - on error callback

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using connect-redis - https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis
in my project.

Is there any on error event? Something, where I can put callback to tell me,
that (for example) my app can't connect to redis server?

I tried to search but I have found nothing useful.

Part of my config code:

```
app.use(express.methodOverride());      
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.logger('dev'));

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'have a fun',
    maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    store: new RedisStore( config[app.get('env')].redis ),
    // store: new FileStore({path:'./data/sessions', useAsync:true})
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use(app.router);
```

Every useful tip is welcome...

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is backed by awesome `node-redis` hence it should have events attached to it like `error` event.

So, considering following is the code you are using to create an object -

```
var session = require('express-session'),
    RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
RedisStore.on('error', function(err){ 
  console.log("Connection error.");
})
```

Above code is not tested, but it should work.

Just take Redis server down and then start node server, it should print the log.
If this works, then go [here](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) and you will find more 5 events and some more stuff.